# ISAPI redirect non-www to www without default

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, isapi, ektron

I'm trying to get my site to redirect from non-www to www, and I have implemented the code that does that which works.  However, when it redirects it tacks on default.aspx, and it's throwing my Google Analytics stats way off.  Is there a way to do this redirect without it sending me to the default page?  I'm using the Ektron CMS if this makes a difference.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be better handled with a DNS redirect so the site doesn't have to worry about it. A lot of registrars have this tool right in the dashboard.